# App working on simulator but not on iPhone( dyld`__abort_with_payload dyld`_dyld_start)

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to **Xcode** the build succeeded app installed on phone but quits or have white screen

> dyld`__abort_with_payload
>
> dyld`_dyld_start

**dyld__abort_with_payload:**

[image]

**dyld_dyld_start:**

[image]

> **build error:Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer **

[image]

Comment: please past error from console. I see in images that there are :)

Comment: Here https://imgur.com/a/c3yw2

Comment: Any answer to this? I'm having the same issue and I have found no way to save my project.

Comment: @VagueExplanation In keychain, for iPhone certificates previously I changed the iPhone developer Keychain from default to always trust. Coming back to system default it worked.
Then the build succeeded with no warnings and app worked on phone perfectly
i suggest you delete all certificates in keychain and again build app in Xcode Xcode will ask for keychain password put again and again .
make sure iPhone developer certificates are on 'default' not 'always trust'

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when I changed the iPhone developer Keychain in my Mac from default to always trust. Coming back to system default worked

**Keychain certificates**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhyoA.png

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your trust settings to system default
2. Delete all certificates in your local keychain
3. Quit and relaunch xcode
4. Clean
5. Run program on device
6. When it asks, enter your keychain password and click always trust

I was dealing with this issue for a couple days and tore my hair out looking for help. This was the only post that worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Closing Xcode and cleaning the project solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just cleaning fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened when trying to build for iOS 13. It was about `Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description` key that was missing from my `.plist` file.