# Not able to deploy flutter application to iOS Appstore

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store

While Building the app for iOS Distribution in flutter I faced the below issue with the build, I tried many things available on google related to this issue but no resolution yet.

How am I supposed to deploy flutter application to iOS Appstore?

```
 Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Distribution: Mark Davids (*********)"
    /Users/mark/Downloads/chat_app-master 2/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App: errSecInternalComponent
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Encountered error while building for device.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911289/warning-unable-to-build-chain-to-self-signed-root-for-signer-warning-in-xcode

Comment: @Haryanvi 'Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority' this is the CA I am using , how should I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a vague error, however my guess is its 1 of two things.

1. There is Flutter detritus that is blocking your build, which you can fix by running the `flutter clean` command
2. Your certificate is invalid. When dealing with this in the past I have found the easiest way to fix it is to open XCode, set the signing to none, purge your certificates and keys from your system, and then re-add them to the keychain.

Comment: as per this documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios , first is used `flutter build ios` after which the above error is there

Comment: Have you configured signing in your XCode project

Comment: yes, I configured the signing in Xcode project manually, automatic signing was showing profiling error

Comment: This is a problem with your XCode certificates. A few things this could be:

1. Your certificate has expired
2. You are missing a keyfile on your computer

My best solution to this would be removing all certificates from your computer, then generate a new certificate from developer.apple.com