# XCode Build is working fine but cant archive my App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I cant archive my iOS app for some reason but its working all fine on the Build on debug and release mode both.

That's the error i am getting :

Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: (MY DEVELOPER NAME) (ID)"

/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PSHotels-cmlgwueeqxkynaewfwzpeiuqoeyr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Serai Rooms/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Serai Rooms.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: errSecInternalComponent

**Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**

Things i already tried :

1. Deleting derived data
2. Lock and unlock the login fro Keychain
3. Restarting Mac and Xcode

Comment: Make sure your Mac has distribution certificates and try it once.

Comment: @KrishnarjunBanoth I have it and i also tried changing the Trust setting but still not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911289/warning-unable-to-build-chain-to-self-signed-root-for-signer-warning-in-xcode

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now resolved.

You need to delete all your developer account certificates and and also remove the account.
Then add the account and let the Xcode create new certificates for you. And then try archiving the project. Thats how my problem got solved.