# iOS swiftUI app on the test device, an error occurs. "Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: ios, xcode, build, certificate, keychain

It was confirmed that it was working normally when building and running the simulation.
However, when I connect it to my iPhone 6S+ and proceed with the build, an error like the one in the picture occurs:

> `Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code`

[image]

I tried setting my certificate to "always trust" in keychain but it didn't solve the error

xCode version is 11.1 and
Mac OS is BIg Sur 11.5.2.

Please, if anyone has encountered the same problem, please help me in resolving this problem.

Comment: I am now trying to upgrade the version of xCode.

Comment: I have encountered this problem before try cleaning the build folder.
`Product` -> `Clean build folder`

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911289/warning-unable-to-build-chain-to-self-signed-root-for-signer-warning-in-xcode) appears to have a similar issue. Check it out!