# Flutter does not build the project on real iOS device: PhaseScriptExecution

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-build, flutter-ios-build

When I want to run my flutter application on the real iOS device, I get this error. I know, 2 weeks ago it worked nicely, but in this 2 weeks I developed lots of feature, and lastly permission handler future, and now I can not run the project on my real device. It's working on iOS simulator excellent.

So, let me tell you what I tried:

```
flutter pub cache repair
flutter clean
flutter run
pod install
pod install --repo-update
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Also, in the Xcode, I tried to build the app. What I get from there?

```
error build: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

[image: Xcode settings]

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Alper Efe iPhone’u in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: ***
Running pod install...                                             15.9s
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                           128.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-12-14 22:35:10.858 xcodebuild[27821:520269]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot2/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-21157/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:382
    Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008030-001629E10185402E was NULL when -platform called.
    Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x149f17050>
    Method:   -platform
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x139f05830>{number = 3, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/fp/t7xmc4k101g4g1p4nnr63skh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.suJrEq/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirIzfHDH/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    1 warning generated.
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1461:38: warning: variable 'sum_left' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
        const uint16x8_t sum = vaddq_u16(sum_left, sum_top);
                                         ^~~~~~~~
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1426:3: note: variable 'sum_left' is declared here
      uint16x8_t sum_left;
      ^
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1461:48: warning: variable 'sum_top' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
        const uint16x8_t sum = vaddq_u16(sum_left, sum_top);
                                                   ^~~~~~~
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1425:3: note: variable 'sum_top' is declared here
      uint16x8_t sum_top;
      ^
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1550:38: warning: variable 'sum_left' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
        const uint16x8_t sum = vaddq_u16(sum_left, sum_top);
                                         ^~~~~~~~
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1509:3: note: variable 'sum_left' is declared here
      uint16x8_t sum_left;
      ^
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1550:48: warning: variable 'sum_top' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
        const uint16x8_t sum = vaddq_u16(sum_left, sum_top);
                                                   ^~~~~~~
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1508:3: note: variable 'sum_top' is declared here
      uint16x8_t sum_top;
      ^
    4 warnings generated.
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:725:12: warning: variable 'best_offset' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
              (best_offset << MAX_LENGTH_BITS) | (uint32_t)best_length;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:657:20: note: initialize the variable 'best_offset' to silence this warning
        int best_offset;
                       ^
                        = 0
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swift:39:52: warning: using 'class' keyword to define a class-constrained protocol is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDataSource: class {
                                                       ^~~~~
                                                       AnyObject
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swift:55:50: warning: using 'class' keyword to define a class-constrained protocol is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDelegate: class {
                                                     ^~~~~
                                                     AnyObject
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swift:39:52: warning: using 'class' keyword to define a class-constrained protocol is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDataSource: class {
                                                       ^~~~~
                                                       AnyObject
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swift:55:50: warning: using 'class' keyword to define a class-constrained protocol is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDelegate: class {
                                                     ^~~~~
                                                     AnyObject
    /Users/sahinefe/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-4.6.1/ios/Classes/FilePickerPlugin.m:357:1: warning: implementing deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]
    - (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url{
    ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/file_picker/file_picker-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIDocumentPickerViewController.h:27:1: note: method 'documentPicker:didPickDocumentAtURL:' declared here
    - (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("documentPicker:didPickDocumentsAtURLs:", ios(8.0, 11.0));
    ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/sahinefe/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4.2.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:103:72: warning: sending 'FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<FLTFirebasePlugin> _Nonnull'
        [[FLTFirebasePluginRegistry sharedInstance] registerFirebasePlugin:self];
                                                                           ^~~~
    In module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/sahinefe/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4.2.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:7:
    /Users/sahinefe/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2.4.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.h:23:64: note: passing argument to parameter 'firebasePlugin' here
    - (void)registerFirebasePlugin:(id<FLTFirebasePlugin> _Nonnull)firebasePlugin;
                                                                   ^
    1 warning generated.
    1 warning generated.

    Failed to package /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'libwebp' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'libPhoneNumber-iOS' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'SwiftyGif' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'SDWebImage' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'Libuv-gRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Libuv-gRPC' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreInternal' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreExtension' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'DKPhotoGallery-DKPhotoGallery' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'DKPhotoGallery' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'DKImagePickerController-DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sahinefe/Documents/Github/flutter_production_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/fp/t7xmc4k101g4g1p4nnr63skh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.suJrEq/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirIzfHDH/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

It appears that your application still contains the default signing identifier.
Try replacing 'com.example' with your signing id in Xcode:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on Alper Efe iPhone’u.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, to see more details of the problem I run the following code line:

```
 flutter run -v
```

then I realize that I have problem that related to "codesign".

Next, I did lots of research about the problem, and I saw almost everywhere the "certificate" problem.

Especially this link helped me a lot: ["Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer" warning in Xcode 9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911289/warning-unable-to-build-chain-to-self-signed-root-for-signer-warning-in-xcode)

Apart from that, I remove my certificates from the system and login sections, but when I remove from the login, it recreated again IDK why. Then, I disable auto sign in section in the Xcode, and again re-enable it. After I click the build button in Xcode it built the app successfully. Then I opened the vscode and it's also built as well.

By the way, lastly, I also did 9.3 to 11.0 compatibilityVersion property.

Comment: I think the thing was to remove other certificates from the system section. I had 3 certificates, but right now just 1 that expires on 2030